# Get proper output from a decrypted text

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I am working on a encryption and decryption using public and private keys in python.I have encrypted the text and am trying to decrypt it however, I get the actual message at the end of some random text! can I get help to understand what I am doing wrong?

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5

msg = "supriya"
print("raw msg->", msg)
public_key_string = open("key.pem","r").read()
keyPub = RSA.importKey(public_key_string) # import the public key
cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(keyPub)
#print(cipher.encrypt.__doc__)
cipher_text = cipher.encrypt(msg.encode()) # now we have the cipher
'print("cipher text->", cipher_text)'

private_key_string = open("key2.py","r").read()
private_key = RSA.importKey(private_key_string)
print(private_key)
decrypted = private_key.decrypt(cipher_text)
print(decrypted)
```

When I try to `print(decrypted)` I get :

```
b"\x02\x1cL`(\xf8\xbb\x84Eg\xc2\xf2Z\xa7\xa3\x10\xd06\x9a\x05
\xbd\xd0\x9e$\x94\x89\xd4\x04M\x7f\xb8\xc4\x01k\xf9\x9a\xb6&
\x07\xd6jbw\x9c>\x08\xdb\xe5\xda@\x9b\\\xa5Pz\xe8\x94s4+\xee
]'W.T+\xb6\xd7\x19\x7f\x85tL\xe9J:\x08\xf7\xbd\xbd\xdc\x99ep
\xd5\xea\xf1[\xff\x8a\x1d\xd5#\xd8s\n\xec\xb5,\xde\x1dE\xe7
\x99\x1f(\xbfm=iu1 \xe4^\x18\x10\x06z'\xf4_\x1c\x88[D\xa5
\xe6J\xa8\xf1\x7f\xb4\xe3r\xad)\xcb\xa3\x06\xf9\xbea6A\xf32
\x99\xa3y\xf5\xa3[\xc4m\xa8;\xfa\xcdQc#\xc8\t\x8d\xf8\xcb8
\xadC\xb0\x1c\xe8\x8b\xfc\x9c\x87&K\xd4\xd8\x9c/`\xbd\x92\\
\xc2\xe0:\x13e\x8b\xc9\xd8,p{\xb1@\x80\xbf\xf50\xb8\x84a\x15
\x0cF\xe1\xa4\xea\r\x16\x12:e}Edc\x9e\xa4\xb8\x87u\x1e\xbf
\x17\xf8\\\xeb\x9e\x88\x7f^\xb7\xb1\xa7o{s\x00supriya"
```

Answer (score 1):

You used [PKCS1v1.5 padding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.2.1) on the encryption. Which is probably good, as people who use encryption generally want and expect it to provide security and specifically confidentiality, and RSA encryption without padding in nearly all cases (apparently including yours) is easily broken and not secure. Search 'textbook RSA' or 'RSA no padding' on crypto.SX and security.SX for *many* Q&As on why. (Even v1.5 is not perfect; in some situations it remains vulnerable to an adaptive-ciphertext attack due to Bleichenbacher, also covered on those Stacks, and OAEP is the best currently-standardized padding. But leave that aside.)

But you didn't use it on the decryption. As a result, your decrypted value includes the v1.5 encryption padding, which is an octet with value 2, as many nonzero random octets as needed to make the 'encoded message' (EM) used in the RSA primitive the correct size i.e. the size of the modulus, and one zero octet, followed by the plaintext. You should **use `PKCS1_v1_5` on the decryption** as you did on the encryption (except with the privatekey).